# problem running html or php code in visual studios

Tags: php, html

I was able to run my codes normally on vs. But after intalling some php package its not running or debugging my code instead an error dialogue box keeps popping up everytime I run a code. It says "php executable not found. Install php and add it to your path or set the php.debug.executablepath setting."
Also it opens a new tab on chrome whenever I run a code which displays nothing  but error "try reload this page".
It has url as "localhost:8000".

i tried uninstalling some extensions but it didnt help.
I expect it to run smoothly as it was earlier.

Comment: *“It says "php executable not found. Install php and add it to your path”* Did you try this? Please type `php` in a terminal, and add the output of this command in the question by **Edit**ing it.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't changed anything. Actually codes of HTML and CSS are also not running and showing the same issue.

Comment: Please add the output of `whereis php` in your question.